# select certain elements to build incrementally ioslides

Tags: r, r-markdown, presentation

I'm building a presentation using ioslides in RStudio. 
I have a following slide:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
logo<-"logo.jpg"
```

## Playing with R
<IMG style="position:absolute;top:5.5%;right:5%;width:140px;"SRC="`r logo`">

Type in the interactive console:

```{r, eval=FALSE}
x <- 1:10 # "name <- value returns the value invisibly"
```
```{r, eval=FALSE}
getwd()
```
````

I would like only the code chunks to appear incrementally and text as well as the logo NOT to. I tried to use `<div class="incremental"> </div>`, but this isn't working. Elements are already placed on the slide when move to it. Using {.build} option makes every element to appear incrementally which I want to avoid.

Any suggestions what way I can select only certain elements on slide to appear incrementally?

Comment: I also want to know how to do this. I hope my comment gives this post more attention.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you can use {.build} to incrementally build slides
(see also http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#build_slides). 
It should be possible to use div elements to group the parts that you want to build together:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
logo<-"logo.jpg"
```

## Playing with R {.build}

<div>
<IMG style="position:absolute;top:5.5%;right:5%;width:140px;"SRC="`r logo`">

Type in the interactive console:
</div>

```{r, eval=FALSE}
x <- 1:10 # "name <- value returns the value invisibly"
```

```{r, eval=FALSE}
getwd()
```
````